# Error:- method not found while connecting signalr

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr

having error with signalr. On running application it is showing error "method not found".
having problem in connection.

I'm using signalr for chatting purpose. The project is in Reactjs and asp.net core.
react app is created through creat-react-app (console).

// code in reactjs*****

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HubConnection } from 'signalr-client-react';

class SingnalR extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                bookingMessage: '',
                bookingHubConnection: null
            };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const bookingHubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:5000/chatHub')
        this.setState({ bookingHubConnection }, () => {
            this.state.bookingHubConnection.start()
                .then(() => console.log('Signalr started '))
                .catch((err) => console.log('Error connecting signalr - ' + err));


        this.state.bookingHubConnection.on('booking', (message) => {
            const bookingMessage = message;
            this.setState({ bookingMessage });
        });

    });


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>message from server {this.state.bookingMessage}</div>
                userName <input id="userName" />
                userMessage<input id="userMessage" />
                <button id = "sendMessage"> sendMessage</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SingnalR;
```

//code for asp.net core*******

//code chatHub

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TinyHouseApi.SignalR
{
    public class ChatHub:Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMesage", user, message);
        }
    }
}

//code of Startupfile
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("testDB")));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            //configure SignalR
            services.AddSignalR();

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();

            //SignalR
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            });
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use **signalr-client-react** witch depends on **ms-signalr-client** witch depends on **jquery.signalR.js** witch is the old version of **signalR** client and not compatible with **ASP.Net Core SignalR**.

To use the latest **SignalR** version wit **ASP.Net Core** you should use [@aspnet/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr) package. You cannot use **signalr-client-react**

There is a [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: if i am using @aspnet/signalr in place of signalr-client-react it is leading to following error:- Error: The 'logger' argument is required.

Comment: Without the code I cannot help you, but if it complains for logger pass a logger then